# Post using [FromBody] with reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I have several derived classes is there a way I can create a controller that handles all of them using reflection?

```
[Route("api/{type:regex(forma|formb|formc)}")]
public class FormController : BaseController
{
    ...

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CreateOrUpdateForm([FromBody] FormA forma, string type)
    {
        var formType = GetTypeFromName(type);
        var submitMethod = _formService
            .GetType()
            .GetMethod("SaveForm")
            .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] {formType});
        var savedForm = submitMethod.Invoke(_formService, new object[]{forma});
        return createOkResponse(new
        {
            form = savedForm
        });
    }
}
```

This works when I post a `FormA` object but obviously doesn't if I post a `FormB` or `FormC`. I tried setting it to `[FromBody] BaseForm form` but that didn't work either. Is something like this possible/good idea? The backend logic is all the same for all forms which is why I'm trying to do this

Comment: It is possible. I did it once. In my opinion, it's a terrible idea :-)

Comment: Haha thanks, why do you think it's a terrible idea?

Comment: I don't think the added complexity in reading and debugging the code is worth it. If you encapsulate the shared logic and have a bunch of similar action methods that call it, I doubt you'll find it a burden to maintain and the interface will be a whole easier to understand.

Comment: Yea it definitely does reduce readability. Just having several controllers that were all the same except for the type kind of bugged me

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try this in your controller action parameters:

```
([FromBody] dynamic formObj, string type)
```

dynamic keywords make it so that the compiler determines the objects properties at runtime

Comment: Thanks, I'll look that up and try it

Comment: This is causing some deserialization errors. Thanks though